# Updating multiple tables with one form using VBA on Microsoft Access

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to add a record on the main table whenever I click submit and one field from this table will go to another one of two tables as a new row based on whether i check a checkbox. For some reason, the record only goes into the main table and neither of the other two. Here's my code.

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()
Dim SqlString As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim req As Integer
SqlString = "SELECT * FROM [WorkRecord]"
SqlString1 = "SELECT * FROM [MainWork]"
sqlString2 = "SELECT * FROM [MiscelleneousWork]"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SqlString)

rs.MoveLast
lastnum = rs!WorkNum
rs.AddNew
rs!WorkNum = lastnum + 1
rs!WorkDate = Me.WorkDate.Value
rs!ReqNum = Me.ReqNum.Value
rs.Update

If Me.checkmain.Value = True Then
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(SqlString1)
rs1.MoveLast
lastnum = rs!WorkNum
rs1.AddNew
rs1!WorkNum = lastnum + 1
rs1.Update
rs1.Close
Else
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset(sqlString2)
rs2.MoveLast
lastnum = rs!WorkNum
rs2.AddNew
rs2!WorkNum = lastnum + 1
rs2.Update
rs2.Close
End If

MsgBox ("Work added.")
DoCmd.Close acForm, "AddWorkRecord"
rs.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code?  Have you defined rs1 & rs2 anywhere?  Have you tried a simple `insert into` sql method?

Comment: Indenting the If codes works for me. Thank you.